# How to fix sonar voilations automatically through scripts

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am going to integrate Sonar with the existing code base, with multiple projects, I have plans to make it incremental analysis by using ant script to trigger sonar analysis and make the build fail if there are Blockers or Criticals.

However when i run the sonar on the existing code there are tonnes of issues shown, I would like to fix the issues automatically instead of fixing them manually.

Question: Are there any APIs or Methods to fix the sonar voilations automatically.

IF NOT

Are there any sonar APIs, which gives the error code and place of errors in the source code through a standard format, so that i can spend time in writing API to fix the sonar voilations automatically

Comment: See: https://github.com/walkmod

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any ready made tools for fixing issues found by Sona qube. But if you want to build something I would look into two places:

1. Refactorings of IDEs. Many issues and there fixes boil down to refactorings that are already available in IDEs and two of the big three IDEs are open source.
2. [JaMoPP](http://www.jamopp.org/index.php/JaMoPP) is a tool that can be used for performing refactorings through code. Might be exactly what you are looking for.

Sonar qube is largely based on other tools (Checkstyle, PMD ...) for automatically analysing issues you might be better of using those directly.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this info is definitely helpful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing existing issues automatically - effectively hiding potentially critical issues - I would recommend instead that you create a Quality Profile with let's say 10 or 20 rules, and start fixing those. When your codebase starts growing sane, you can start enabling another batch or rules.

If you still want to deal with issues in bulk, you can use the [SonarQube Web Service API](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=231080558#WebService/api/issues-BulkChangeonIssues) at `http://yourinstance/api/issues/bulk_change` to modify a bunch of issues at once.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this info is definitely helpful.I will try to do what you mentioned.